# Reformat data in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot

Anyone know how I can make the unique items in first column as the rows with the EARLY, LATE, ONTIME as the columns? I tried a pivot table but it seems to only be good for summing, counting...etc. I don't need operations done on the values.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you don't have repeats in your rows then the sum is the same as the value.  Do you have cases where there's more than one row for any combination of ColA and ColB ?

Comment: Yeah, there must be duplicate rows. There were hidden rows and the pivot table was reading them. So I copied them into a new sheet and used that sheet for the pivot table and it worked! Thanks man.